# springjdbc Connection for multipe query

Tags: database, spring, database-connection, spring-jdbc

I am developing Spring Web application where many user interact with database cocurrently.i am using SpringJdbcTemplete for communication with database. I have following two beans define.

    
        
        
        
        
    
 
    
    

I only need one Datasource so its defult scope should be Singleton. I have 
jdbcTemplate bean autowired to different service class(Admin and user service class).Since my application user can concurrently access this jdbcTempelete instance what should be its defult scope..?

I found that it should be Singleton. But If it is Singleton that only one instance of it will be created and is shared among many requesting user.In this secenerio suppose 1000 user try to access jdbcTemplate at the same time that 999 user have to wait to get it. am iwrong in that if yes please help to avoid my confusion. thanks

Comment: You are wrong. The fact that it is a singleton doesn't mean it cannot be used by multiple users. All 100 users can use the same instance concurrently (well of course limited by the amount requests your app server can handle).

Comment: what if i create jdbcTemplate scope a  prototype  will the above explain secenerio will be same or what other thing haped

Comment: That depends on how you use it. But there is no need for making it prototype scoped. Doing that could even make it worse and severely impact your performance.

Comment: According to you remaining 999 user does not have to wait for jdbcTemplate  to get .but there request might be queud until jdbcTemplate  is released by previous your

Comment: so i can define bean as  <!-- Singleton -->
 <beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" /> as autowire it to any of my service class without considering concurreny and connectionpooling issue..?is that...

Comment: No it isn't. There is no blocking and thus x number of threads can concurrently use the same instance. The fact that there are multiple threads and a single instance doesn't imply it is only for single thread use.

Comment: please  clarify your this line i did not get it " The fact that there are multiple threads and a single instance doesn't imply it is only for single thread use"

Comment: There isn't much more to it than the whole line. The fact that you have a single instance of a class doesn't mean it cannot be used concurrently. Those are different things, as long as the class is thread safe there is no issue. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

Comment: JdbcTemplate class is stateless class and so it is thread safe than why didi you say  this" No it isn't. There is no blocking and thus x number of threads can concurrently use the same instance. The fact that there are multiple threads and a single instance doesn't imply it is only for single thread use."

Comment: I didn't say that.. I said that the fact that there is a single instance **doesn't** imply it is only for single thread use.

Comment: With this Discussion,what i gained that my web application will have only one connection to my database server which is shared by different client request handlled in different thread.But some database server offer 20 connection for some extra money.can't my application performance be increased using those 20 connection instead of using one connection for all user request

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) of `JdbcTemplate` the class is thread safe after construction. So as soon as an instance of `JdbcTemplate` is available it can be shared amongst different threads.

The `JdbcTemplate` is thread safe and can be used concurrently between multiple threads.

When a bean is thread safe there is nothing preventing you to use a single instance between any number of threads.

More information on using Spring and JDBC Access can be found in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Comment: With this Discussion,what i gained that  my web application will have only one connection to my database server which is shared by different client request hsndlled in different thread.But some databse server offer 20 connection for some extra money.can't my application performance be increased using those 20 connection instead of using one connection for all user request

Comment: Again your understanding is wrong. If you have a connection pool of 20 the  `JdbcTemplate` will use a fresh connection per thread, or depending on your configuration per query. Instead of guessing I strongly suggest a read of the reference guide...

Comment: please giv me  reference guide link

Comment: what if all 20 pool is occupied by 20 request than what happen?does app wait for connection pool to be release or what

Comment: Well what do you think happens... What is the point of a connection pool?

Comment: Well,request is queued until  an unused connection in present in the connection pool queue.One last quesation who define connection pool setting 1.Programmer during Datasource Configuration or 2.Database Server administrator

Comment: I would say neither. But that is highly opinionated. A nice read on connection pool sizing is [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).